# Create the controller of an upload file form in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, zend-controller

I have created the elements in the form for an upload document but the form has other elements as well. Now I can't seem to find out a way to upload files because no matter what I do is says "File 'img_file' exceeds the defined ini size" even if I try to save only another field in the form.

```
    $file = new \Zend_Form_Element_File('img_file');
    $file->setLabel ( \Zend_Registry::get('config')->form->docFile )
          ->setRequired(false);
```

Also added `->setEnctype(\Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);` for the form

Can somebody help me with the controller since I'm using MVC?

Comment: Pls see [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html)

Comment: I have but that is the case when all the form does is one upload, while my form has more than 5 other fields.